# Excel sheets with employees and dates

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have more than 20 sheets in Excel and one main sheet (all programs with 200 names). Each sheet has a column with names and 24 months (Jan 18 to Dec 18, Jan 19 to Dec 20). Each sheet names is a subset of the main sheet.

Main sheet (all programs) has 200 names and 24 months (values to be calculated based on other sheets). The other sheet has names and values for each month respective to the main sheet. I need to take each name in main sheet and search the name in all other sheets, and if present sum all same column values and insert in the main sheet.

For 1 name I need to do calculation on 34 cells (for 200 names * 34 cells = 6800 cells). It's taking almost 20 minutes with my code. Is there any other way I can do it or any modification which improves the performance?

Main Sheet has name "employee1"

[image]

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

Value on the main sheet should be calculated respect to months

[image]

```
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim datatoFind
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim mainSheet As String: mainSheet = "All Programs"
    Dim nameColumnStart As String: nameColumnStart = "A"

    Dim namesStart As Integer: namesStart = 1
    Dim namesEnd As Integer: namesEnd = 200

    Dim startColumn As Integer: startColumn = 10 'J Column'
    Dim EndColumn As Integer: EndColumn = 33 'AG Column'

    namesStart = InputBox("Please enter start value")
    namesEnd = InputBox("Please enter end value")


    Dim temp_str As String
    Dim total As Single
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(mainSheet).Activate
    lastRow_main = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    lastCol_main = 34
    For vRow = namesStart To namesEnd
        temp_str = Sheets(mainSheet).Cells(vRow, "A").Text
        datatoFind = StrConv(temp_str, vbLowerCase)
            For vCol = startColumn To EndColumn
                total = Find_Data(vCol)
                Worksheets(mainSheet).Cells(vRow, vCol).Value = total
            Next vCol
    Next vRow
    Sheets(mainSheet).Activate
    'MsgBox ("Calculated all values")'
End Sub


Private Function Find_Data(ByVal ColumnName As Integer) As Single
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim currentSheet As Integer
    Dim sheetCount As Integer
    Dim str As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim val As Single

    Find_Data = 0

    currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Index

    If datatoFind = "" Then Exit Function

    sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    For counter = 2 To sheetCount

        Sheets(counter).Activate

        lastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
        lastCol = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

        For vRow = 1 To lastRow
                str = Sheets(counter).Cells(vRow, "A").Text
                If InStr(1, StrConv(str, vbLowerCase), datatoFind) Then
                        val = Sheets(counter).Cells(vRow, ColumnName).Value
                        Find_Data = Find_Data + val
                End If
        Next vRow

    Next counter

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: I've removed the VBScript tag, since this is obviously VBA - and VBScript is a different language. What Toby means is that as it stands, the post's title is essentially "my code runs too slow, how do I make it faster" - which is a title that's applicable to pretty much 90% of the VBA questions on this site. So in order to avoid having a [tag:vba] page filled with nearly-identical titles, we ask that you make your title a short description of what your code does, i.e. it's purpose. As the watermark says: "state the purpose of the code". Thanks

Comment: i changed the title for easy filtering . Thank you @m

Comment: That's.... literally the opposite of what I said.

Comment: Got it , I will change lol

Comment: Not an answer: but (based on your description of the problem) I would first think of creating a union of all the data and creating a pivot table or some simple data structure first. This is using the native Excel functionality rather than trying to duplicate it in VBA.

Comment: Why not use Python?

Comment: @Elmex80s what is the advantage of using Python?

Comment: @TinMan It is a good alternative to VBA.

Answer (score 1):

### Global Variables

> ```
> Dim sheetCount As Integer
> Dim datatoFind
> ```

Global variables make the code harder to maintain, modify, and debug.  It would be better to pass the data as parameters between the sub routines.  This makes it easier to determine exactly what data is being passed into your subroutines.

`Private` or `Public` modifiers should be used instead of `Dim` when declaring a global variable.

### Constant Expressions

> ```
> Dim mainSheet As String: mainSheet = "All Programs"
> Dim nameColumnStart As String: nameColumnStart = "A"
> Dim startColumn As Integer: startColumn = 10 'J Column'
> Dim EndColumn As Integer: EndColumn = 33 'AG Column'
> ```

The variables above should be declared as constants.

> ```
> Const mainSheet As String = "All Programs"
> Const nameColumnStart As String = "A"
> Const startColumn As Integer = 10 'J Column'
> Const EndColumn As Integer = 33 'AG Column'
> ```

### namesStart and namesEnd

Why initiate the values below if you are not going to use the initial values?

> ```
> Dim namesStart As Integer: namesStart = 1
> Dim namesEnd As Integer: namesEnd = 200
>
>
> namesStart = InputBox("Please enter start value")
> namesEnd = InputBox("Please enter end value")
> ```

Consider using [Application.InputBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) because you can specify the type of data it returns.

> ```
> Dim namesStart As Integer
> Dim namesEnd As Integer
> Const namesStartDefault As Integer = 1
> Const namesEndDefault As Integer = 200
>
> namesStart = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter start value", Default:=namesStartDefault, Type:=1)
> namesEnd = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter end value", Default:=namesEndDefault, Type:=1)
>
> If namesStart < namesStartDefault Then
>     MsgBox "Start vaule must be greater than or equal to " & namesStartDefault, vbCritical
>     Exit Sub
> End If
> ```

### Selecting and Activating Objects

Selecting and Activating Objects should be avoided unless absolutely necessary, watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).   I would wager to bet that of the 20 minutes that it takes to run your code 19+ minutes are spent needlessly activating worksheets.

Using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` would probably cut the time in half.

### Function Find_Data

`SpecialCells(xlLastCell)` should only be used when you don't know the data structure.

`lastCol` isn't used.

> ```
>  lastCol = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
> ```

`vRow` is never declared.  The `v` prefix implies a variant when it should clearly be long.

`ColumnName` implies a string value.  I would use `CoumnIndex` instead.

### Refactored Code

```
Private Const mainSheet As String = "All Programs"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const LastColumn = 34
    Dim namesStart As Integer
    Dim namesEnd As Integer
    Const namesStartDefault As Integer = 1
    Const namesEndDefault As Integer = 200

    namesStart = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter start value", Default:=namesStartDefault, Type:=1)
    namesEnd = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter end value", Default:=namesEndDefault, Type:=1)

    If namesStart < namesStartDefault Then
        MsgBox "Start vaule must be greater than or equal to " & namesStartDefault, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mainSheet)
        For r = namesStartDefault To namesEndDefault
            For c = 2 To LastColumn
                .Cells(r, c).Value = Find_Data(.Cells(r, 1).Value, c)
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Private Function Find_Data(ByVal EmployeeName As String, ByVal ColumnIndex As Integer) As Single
    Dim result As Single
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If Not .Name = mainSheet Then
                For r = 2 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    If InStr(1, .Cells(r, 1).Value, EmployeeName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        result = result + .Cells(r, ColumnIndex).Value
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Find_Data = result
End Function
```